# Displaying PDF attributes in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, webforms

I am looking for a way to manipulate a PDF and return attributes like:

- font color
- font size
- counting words
- line spacing etc.

I am building a asp.net web forms website and users should be able to upload PDF's and get their results displayed on the website. I have already searched for .NET PDF libraries like iTextSharp or PDFClown, but these kinds of libraries aren't good in manipulating PDFs. How can I solve my problem? Which library should I use?

Comment: you are talking about a) manipulating (=modifying) and b) returning statistical information (=read-only). what exactly do you need? if you mean a read-only variant, it is not clear what you expect to return for example for font color: how many different colors, a list of colors used, ...? if you're just asking for a library recommendation, it's off topic.

Comment: My mistake. I want to get statistical informations about a pdf like a list of all font-colors that are used in the pdf or a list of all used font sizes.

Edit: The reason why i said manipulation is, that in future i want to add comments to the uploaded pdf, when an uploader uses a wrong font-family or font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) (I work for them). The library can extract text (formatted or not) and it can extract words and individual characters too.

For extracted words you can get information about the font used to draw the word. This includes color and size. There is also other information available (see PdfTextData class).

Please take a look at the following sample code:

- [Extract text by words](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Text/ExtractTextByWords)

Comment: I am currently evaluating a library for one of our project. Is the Docotic.Pdf library supports displaying the PDF on the browser and the ability to annotate on top of it and also extracting text based on what the user selects on the browser PDF view?

Comment: @Thangadurai Please contact support@bitmiracle.com or ask a new question here.